# Проблемы с авторизацией через Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Делаю авторизацию с помощью Devise. Проблема в том, что при регистрации нового пользователя появляется ошибка

```
Routing Error No route matches [POST] "/users/sign_up"
```

Я новичок в rails,поэтому буду рад любой помощи по данному вопросу

Мой routes.rb выглядит так:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  devise_for :users, :controllers => { :omniauth_callbacks => "callbacks" }
  resources :posts
  root 'posts#index', as: 'home'
  root 'user_registration#new'
  resources :posts do
    resources :comments
  end

  get ':controller(/:action(/:id(.:format)))'
  get 'about' => 'pages#about', as:'about'

  post ':controller(/:action(/:id(.:format)))'
  post ':controller(user_registration(/:action(/:id(.:format)))'

end
```

результат `rake routes`

```
new_user_password_path        GET     /users/password/new(.:format) devise/passwords#new   
edit_user_password_path       GET     /users/password/edit(.:format) devise/passwords#edit   
user_password_path            PATCH   /users/password(.:format) devise/passwords#update  
                              PUT     /users/password(.:format) devise/passwords#update  
                              POST    /users/password(.:format) devise/passwords#create  
cancel_user_registration_path GET     /users/cancel(.:format) devise/registrations#cancel  
new_user_registration_path    GET     /users/sign_up(.:format) devise/registrations#new  
edit_user_registration_path   GET     /users/edit(.:format) devise/registrations#edit  
user_registration_path        PATCH   /users(.:format) devise/registrations#update  
                              PUT     /users(.:format) devise/registrations#update 
                              DELETE  /users(.:format) devise/registrations#destroy  
                              POST    /users(.:format) devise/registrations#create  
new_user_confirmation_path    GET     /users/confirmation/new(.:format) devise/confirmations#new  
user_confirmation_path        GET     /users/confirmation(.:format) devise/confirmations#show  
                              POST    /users/confirmation(.:format) devise/confirmations#create
```

Супер!Спасибо!
С этим я вроде как разобрался,теперь загвоздка в другом.
При попытке отправить @mail повторно те "Конмфирнуть"
Выходит ошибка об ошибке получается)

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `error_notification' for #<Ac
tionView::Helpers::FormBuilder:0x000000000f140ca8>):
    1: <h2>Resend confirmation instructions</h2>
    2
    3: <%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: confirmation_path(res
ource_name), html: { method: :post }) do |f| %>
    4:   <%= f.error_notification %>
    5:   <%= f.full_error :confirmation_token %>
    6:
    7:   <div class="form-inputs">

app/views/devise/confirmations/new.html.erb:4:in `block in _app_views_devis
e_confirmations_new_html_erb__768788303_126423300'
app/views/devise/confirmations/new.html.erb:3:in `_app_views_devise_confirm
ations_new_html_erb__768788303_126423300'
```

Ругается именно на эту строчку:  `<%= f.error_notification %>`

Comment: Добавьте к вопросу полный стектрейс ошибки, пожалуйста

Comment: Добрый день!
Эту проблему я каким-то "магическим" образом решил)
теперь при регистрации нового пользователя выскакивает "Routing Error
No route matches [POST] "/users/sign_up""
мои пути выглядят так

Comment: Пожалуйста, воспользуйтесь функцией редактирования вопроса, чтобы добавить к нему новую информацию, а не создавайте для этого ответ

Comment: Вы в routes.rb что-то исправляли? У вас registrations#create почему-то указывает на /users/confirmation/new, а должна как раз на /users/sign_up

Comment: нет,ничего не исправлял.Что исправить сейчас?

Comment: Отформатировала, стало понятнее, что в ваших роутах всё нормально. Выложите (сразу в вопрос) пожалуйста польный стектрейс ошибки. Вот как вы её в логах сервера видите, скопируйте оттуда от начала до конца, лучше даже весь лог этого экшна

Comment: `error_notification` - это метод SimpleForm, у вас стоит этот гем? Кстати, когда вносите изменения в вопрос, желательно упомянуть в комментах того, кто об этом попросил, не всегда комментаторы вспоминают, что в вопросе надо ткнуть в кнопочку "Отслеживать" :) Упоминание стандартно начинается с @

Comment: @Василиса так вроде правильно?)
Да у меня стоит "gem simple-form" 
Я использую его в своих комментариях
Это как то влияет на приложение?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`error_notification` - это метод SimpleForm, чтобы он заработал, хелпер `form_for` надо заменить на `simple_form_for`. Вам нужно это сделать во всех девайсовых формах

```
<%= simple_form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: confirmation_path(resource_name), html: { method: :post }) do |f| %>
```

Судя по всему, SimpleForm вы поставили уже после девайса. Можно удалить все девайсовые вьюхи и сгенерировать их снова (если вы не вносили туда особых изменений), тогда SimpleForm подхватится автоматически. Вот [тут](https://github.com/heartcombo/simple_form/wiki/Simple-Form-with-Devise) подробнее

Comment: @ Василиса
!!!
Спасибо)
сейчас все исправлю)

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста :) [Примите ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), если он решит вашу проблему, если нет - задавайте вопросы тут в комментах

Comment: вы гений),все супер работает)

Comment: Сейчас опять задам глупый вопрос,но вот так:
"NameError in Devise::RegistrationsController#create
uninitialized constant Devise::MyMailer"
Происходит это событие при нажатии кнопки: 
Didn't receive confirmation instructions?

Comment: @Howen а что у вас в create и кто такой MyMailer? Будет лучше, если вы создадите про это новый вопрос и там всё опишете. За комплимент спасибо :)

Comment: @Василса  ,ищите меня на новых ветках "stackoverflow")